# Flask api representation affects all the views

Tags: python, rest, flask, mime-types, flask-restful

I need to have two logically identical views to response the same data in different content types. I use Flask RESTful.

```
APP = flask.Flask(__name__)
API = flask_restful.Api(APP)

@API.representation('text/csv')                                               
def output_csv(data, code, headers=None):                                     
    data_is_list = isinstance(data, types.ListType)                           
    keys = data[0].keys() if data_is_list else data.keys()                    
    output = io.BytesIO()                                                     
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, keys)                                     
    writer.writeheader()                                                      
    encode = lambda v: v.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(                       
            v, types.UnicodeType) else v                                      
    if data_is_list:                                                          
        writer.writerows([{k: encode(v) for k, v in i.items()} for i     in data])
    else:                                                                     
        writer.writerow({k: encode(v) for k, v in data.items()})              

    resp = flask.make_response(output.getvalue(), code)                       
    resp.headers.extend(headers or {})                                        

    return resp                                                               


class BaseAction(flask_restful.Resource):
    def get(self, id=None):
        # ...
        return actions[0] if id else actions # Dict or list of dicts.


class ActionAsCSV(BaseAction):
    def get(self, id=None):
        data = super(ActionAsCSV, self).get(id, closed)
        flask.Response(data, mimetype='text/csv')      
        return data
```

There are several problems. After I added the representation view all the views return text/csv data with the apprpriate header. **How to use the first view class to return application/json data and the second one to return text/csv data?** The second issue is return value of CSV get method, if I return response object `return flask.Response(data, mimetype='text/csv')` a data become malformed - only keys without values. **How to enable different mimetype without data damage?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, please note that you should not use the same resource to return either a single action or a list of actions. You should use two different resources:

```
class Action(flask_restful.Resource):
    def get(self, action_id):
        return actions[action_id]

class ActionList(flask_restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return actions
```

Then, the simplest way to return different media types for the same resource is to use content negotiation. In this case, you do not need to declare a dedicated resource `ActionAsCSV` to specifically handle the case of returning a response in CSV format. For example, to use content negotiation with **curl**:

`curl -iH "Accept: text/csv" http://URL_TO_YOUR_VIEW`

Moreover, **Flask-RESTful** automatically add the right **content-type** header for you in the returned response: you do not need to define it in the `get` method of your resource.

Also, the API is configured by default to return representations in JSON. However, you can modify that as follow:

```
api = flask_restful.Api(app, default_mediatype="text/csv")
```

If you absolutly want two different resources to handle either **application/json** or **text/csv**, withous using content negotiation and no fallback media type, this is possible:

```
api = flask_restful.Api(app, default_mediatype=None)

class ActionListMixin(object):
    def get(self):
        return actions

class JsonActionList(ActionListMixin, flask_restful.Resource):
    representations = {'application/json': output_json}

class CsvActionList(ActionListMixin, flask_restful.Resource):
    representations = {'text/csv': output_csv}
```

Anoter similar option is to define representation transformers when adding your resources:

```
api = flask_restful.Api(app, default_mediatype=None)

class ActionList(flask_restful.Resource):
    def __init__(self, representations=None):
        self.representations = representations
        super(ActionList, self).__init__()

    def get(self):
        return actions

api.add_resource(ActionList, '/actions_json', resource_class_kwargs={'representations': {'application/json': output_json}})
api.add_resource(ActionList, '/actions_csv', resource_class_kwargs={'representations': {'text/csv': output_csv}})
```